# coloring nodes in iGraph

Tags: r, igraph, data-manipulation

`HAVE` is a data frame with musical `Artists`, their `Friends`, and the `Genre` of the `Artists`:

```
Artist         Friend       ArtistGenre
2 Chainz       Boy Wonder   HIPHOP
2 Chainz       Chris Brown  HIPHOP
2 Chainz       Drake        HIPHOP
Billy Joel     Cindi Lauper ROCK
Blake Shelton  Gwen Stefani COUNTRY
```

`NEED` is a graph showing connections between `Artist` and `Friend`, where all people in `Artist` have a node color varying by `ArtistGenre`.

I produce a graph without conditionally colored nodes here:

`x <- graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(HAVE[,1:2]), directed = F)
plot.igraph(x, vertex.label=NA, vertex.size=1.5)`

But changing the node colors by `Genre` is proving quite difficult. How do I map `ArtistGenre` to node colors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it.  This will colour the Artist nodes by genre, keeping the Friend nodes as white.  I have added labels and made the nodes bigger so that you can see what is happening...

```
plot.igraph(x, 
            vertex.label = vertex.attributes(x)$name, 
            vertex.size = 25,
            vertex.color = match(vertex.attributes(x)$name,
                                 HAVE$Artist))
```

[image]

Comment: What does match do here?

Comment: @jjmerelo It is a base R lookup function that returns the position of the first argument in the second - so `match("B", c("A", "B", "C"))` is 2, for example.